# as3 extended classes doesn't understand updates

Tags: actionscript-3, gaia

I think my flash has a curse.

I use Flash Professional CS5.5 with Gaia FrameWork in my project. movieclips in the project have extended classes and the problem is that when I give new functionality to my classes they doesn't work in an build project. for example function s cann't be found, trace doesn't work and so on. All the old functionality works. When I change class name then it works fine. but then it happens again. 
I made new project and coped all the content, but still it happens. I event rainstalled flash but nothing works. 
What can I do?

Comment: are you giving the library item linkage the same name as the base class name? eg) your linkage is called `MyClip`, and you're setting the base class to `com.foo.MyClip`? Doing so can cause some unexpected issues. It could also be an inheritance issue, different library items that share the same custom base classes cannot have assets on their timelines with the same instance names.

Comment: also, if you can post the exact error messages, that could help narrow down the problem.

Comment: no they don't have same name. I have to rename my classes when ever I give some new functionality, so it is calles class1, class2 and so on.

Comment: And what about error, the thing is that it doesn't throw errors, it just cann't understand new functions and variables that i declare in class. Strange think is that when I deleted problematic classes and left movieclips without base classes in the library. old functionality still worked. I told you it's a curse

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from a network drive? Sometimes if your system time and the network time are out of sync Flash thinks your class files haven't changed and does not bother to recompile the latest changes.

When testing your project compile like this: Go to Control > Delete ASO files and test movie.

This option deletes the compiled cache and forces it to be rebuilt ...

Comment: Go to Control > Delete ASO files and test movie doesn't help, only help is renaming classes, but anyway thanks